# Conditional table cell background color depending on value

Tags: html, jquery, conditional-formatting

I have a HTML table that I'm trying to change the cell background color to red depending on the value of the cell. Each cell will have a different threshold for when red is needed (one cell might be > 5, another > 10). The cells are sporadic throughout the table, and none are related to the other. Further, jquery is used to pull the value in from a value stored in a SharePoint list. Is there some way to check the value when it's pulled from the list and change the color before it's inserted in the table? Not sure what the best approach is for this. Thanks in advance for any help offered!

Table row code:

```
<tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="width:30%; background-color:#015A78; color:White; text-align:center; 
 font-size:20pt; font-weight:bold; border-width:thick; border-style:inset"><div 
 id="subjectivehoverMouseover" title="">Subjective</div></td>

      <td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border- 
 style:inset"><div id="SubjectiveDays"></div></td>
      <td></td>

     </tr>
```

And the jquery to pull in the value for SubjectiveDays in the last cell above:

```
 if (listItem.Title === "subjectivegrading") {
               $("#SubjectiveDays").text(listItem.c3t9 + " Business Days");
            }
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the `c3t9` value is the 5, 10 or whatever?

Comment: Correct. The c3t9 value will change. Depending on the user input on a different SP page, the value in the list will change. Then that value from the list is being pulled into a single cell in a table.

Comment: Based on the value, then you could apply CSS. Seems odd, though, that multiple elements will have the same `SubjectiveDays` id?

Comment: No, each cell has a separate id. This is just one example/cell. I'm hoping if I can figure out how to do it in one cell, I can copy it to the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go with one cell, using your example that I copied for two others, changing the ID, could look something like this:

```js
let listItem = {};
listItem.Title = 'subjectivegrading';
listItem.c3t9 = 5;

if (listItem.Title === "subjectivegrading") {
   $("#SubjectiveDays").text(listItem.c3t9 + " Business Days");
   $("#SubjectiveDays").addClass('red');
}

listItem.c3t9 = 10;
if (listItem.Title === "subjectivegrading") {
   $("#SubjectiveDays2").text(listItem.c3t9 + " Business Days");
   $("#SubjectiveDays2").addClass('yellow');
}

listItem.c3t9 = 15;
if (listItem.Title === "subjectivegrading") {
   $("#SubjectiveDays3").text(listItem.c3t9 + " Business Days");
   $("#SubjectiveDays3").addClass('green');
}
```

```css
.red {
   color: red;
}

.yellow {
   color: yellow;
}

.green {
   color: green;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
      <td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border- 
 style:inset"><div id="SubjectiveDays"></div></td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border- 
 style:inset"><div id="SubjectiveDays2"></div></td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border- 
 style:inset"><div id="SubjectiveDays3"></div></td>
      <td></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

However, you would probably want to make a function to pass a cell's ID reference and the `listItem.c3t9` value to apply the CSS in more helpful way, and that could look something like this:

```js
let listItem = {};
listItem.Title = 'subjectivegrading';
listItem.c3t9 = 5;

function setElementCSS(elementRef, listItem) {
  if (listItem.Title === "subjectivegrading") {
     $('#' + elementRef).text(listItem.c3t9 + " Business Days");
     
     addCSS = '';
     
     if (listItem.c3t9 > 10) {
         addCSS = 'green';
     } else if (listItem.c3t9 > 5) {
         addCSS = 'yellow';
     } else {
         addCSS = 'red';
     }

     $('#' + elementRef).addClass(addCSS);
  }
}

setElementCSS('SubjectiveDays', listItem);

listItem.c3t9 = 10;
setElementCSS('SubjectiveDays2', listItem);

listItem.c3t9 = 15;
setElementCSS('SubjectiveDays3', listItem);
```

```css
.red {
   color: red;
}

.yellow {
   color: yellow;
}

.green {
   color: green;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
      <td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border- 
 style:inset"><div id="SubjectiveDays"></div></td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border- 
 style:inset"><div id="SubjectiveDays2"></div></td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border- 
 style:inset"><div id="SubjectiveDays3"></div></td>
      <td></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: I got it to work, thank you so much for all of your help!!